# How to use multiple methods for a string

Tags: java, string, methods

I would like to use multiple method parameters for an if statement,containing the variable "userInput" but im not sure how to go about it. i want java to verify the correct input from the user with .equals while also having the parameter be unaffected by uppercase with .equalsIgnoreCase method simultaneously, but i can't find anywhere how since im not sure how to look that up without getting something else.

i want to also include a "equalsIgnoreCase" method in here!

```
 if (userInput.equals("Circle"))
                 {
                 System.out.println("You have picked a circle");
                 System.out.println("Enter the radius");
                 radius = scanner.nextDouble();}
```

Comment: Do you have an unexpected result when you make userInput.equalsIgnoreCase ("Circle")??

Comment: You can use if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("circle"))  Which does not need to be added with equals check as equalsIgnoreCase check itself is enough. If you want to combine multiple condition you can use &&. For eg. if (userInput.equals("Circle") && userInput.equals("Semicircle "))  {}

Comment: There are two aspects to your question, the answer provided by @fedup answers how to use multiple conditions in if statement, but in your case you don't really need that. The equalsIgnoreCase should handle both inputs "circle" or "Circle". If you are trying to do something else than your question is not clear please provide more input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question exactly you would use the OR (||) operator in the if statement.  For more details see [Oracles Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).  But more to the point, your question is asking to do something that is redundant.

```
if (userInput.equals("Circle") || userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Circle"))
```

Comment: If `userInput.equals("Circle")` is true, then `userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Circle")` is true too, so `userInput.equals("Circle")` is *redundant!*

Comment: Result of `userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Circle")` is always a super set of `userInput.equals("Circle")`

Comment: I changed my answer to say "is redundant".